# Optional URL parameters in Symfony

Tags: symfony, url, router

I currently have this page:

```
my_homepage:
    pattern:  /items/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
      page: \d+
```

So currently I can go to http://example.com/items/ and it will show page 1. I can go to http://example.com/items/1 and it would show page 1 as well, http://example.com/items/2 would show page 2, and so on.

I want to retain this style of URL.

But I also want to have an *optional* parameter in there such that I could go to:

- http://example.com/items/danger
- http://example.com/items/danger/1
- http://example.com/items/danger/2
- etc...

Or

- http://example.com/items/unclassified
- http://example.com/items/unclassified/1
- http://example.com/items/unclassified/2 etc...

So obviously "danger" and "unclassified" is in the place of the new optional parameter (let's call it **{type}**).

Basically the original example would show everything, whereas the last 2 (with "danger" and "unclassified") would filter the listing and only show certain items.

So my question is, what do I do in my router and my controller to be able to have that optional parameter between "items" and the "page number" (if the page number is specified)?

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two optional arguments, you may create an alias of your route:

```
my_homepage:
    pattern:  /items/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page: \d+

my_homepage_with category:
    pattern:  /items/{category}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index, page: 1}
    requirements:
        page: \d+
        category: \w+
```

Your indexAction controller needs an optional category argument

```
public function indexAction($page, $category = null)
{
    //...
```